# Updating GridView with asynctask

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-asynctask

I have read in many places that you can't access a gridview from outside the ui thread, but I believe that's what is causing the problem of my gridview taking long to load. I have it with 75 images and it makes the ui hang so it looks like my app is frozen. Is there a way to use async task to load the images into the grid view off the ui thread? or is there a different way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bosko mentioned, you need to "lazy" load your images off the main UI thread. I find a great way to take away all the pain of doing this is to use a library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) which makes it dead simple. It handles all of pitfalls you will encounter if you try to create a lazy loader yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that library was easy to set up but I have 1 question about it. Do you know how to use a drawable reference instead of a url? I tried to use urls.add("drawable://" + R.drawable.image); but it made the imageview empty.

Comment: Yes it can load resources: Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1); from the page

Answer (score 0):

You should to consider lazy loader for the images.

I suggest you that you change the approach: 
Display all data except images immediately, then load images with lazy loader. You can even implement image cache if the images are repeated.

That approach will increase speed of your UI and then it doesn't like that app is frozen.